# Grammar: sentence structure

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

Do these sentences have identical meanings and are they grammatically correct?

1. What colour is her hair?
2. What is her hair colour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question asks is "the colour (of her hair)" the same as "her hair colour"

Normally these would be equivalent.  Sometimes, in context, "hair colour" might mean the same as "hair dye", so it would be possible, in context, for "What is her hair colour" to mean "What brand of hair dye does she have?".  The first expression is the normal way of asking about someone's appearance.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the *second* form is mainly restricted to contexts where the two-word collocation ***hair colour*** is being treated as a "category" for ***matching*** purposes. So *What is her hair colour?* can be lumped together with *What hair colour **is she**?*, same as, for example, *What **shoe size** are you?, What **fuel type** is your car?*, etc. (where it's also okay to reverse those elements and query *what **colour hair, size shoe, type fuel***.) These "noun attribute" versions typically occur in the context of hairdressers, shoe salesmen, auto mechanics, etc.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Would it be possible to put up such interrogations as: 1."What colour carpet is there in the kitchen?", 2."What coloured carpet is there in the kitchen?", 3."What colour is the carpet there in the kitchen?", 4."What is the carpet's colour there in the kitchen?", 4.""What is the colour of the carpet there in the kitchen?". Thank you.

Comment: Who has carpet in the kitchen?

Comment: @Eugene: Expanding on the implications of James' response, "What colour carpet is there in the kitchen?" would be "unusual" - it presupposes that the questioner is interested in knowing the different colours of various carpets in the relevant context (your house?), *and* it specifically presupposes the questioner knows you have carpet in your *kitchen*. In the real world, it's difficult to imagine #1 being asked as a natural question, but syntactically / idiomatically, it's fine. None of your other suggestions are idiomatic, mainly because of the ways they use the word "there".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you. I had been turning over the construction "There is/are X in the Y" and possible ways of asking questions about the colour, size etc. of X considering the presense of an adverbial modifier. It seemed interesting to me how could "What colour is the X?" transform if an adjunct (of place, for example, were to be added)? "There are carperts in the living-room and in the bedroom in my new home". Someone wants to ask a question about the colour of the carpet in the bedroom.

Comment: If I get off "there", would it be grammatically correct to say: "What colour is the carpet in the bedroom in your new home?"

Comment: Yes, "What colour is the carpet in the bedroom in your new home?" is fine, though I'd probably reduce it to "What colour is the bedroom carpet in your new home?". Bear in mind both of those might tend to imply there's only *one* bedroom in the new home, which implication could be avoided by shifting the possessive: "What colour is **your** bedroom carpet in **the** new home?"

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you very much for having attended to my question.